# C++ - calling a member function of another class using a pointer

Tags: c++

I'm testing, trying to call a member function being passed as a parameter,
the member function has to be one of another class.
this is an example, which gives an error:

> "pointer-to-member selection class types are incompatible ("B" and
> "A")"

This is the code, what am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
private:
public:
    void fA(int x) {
        cout << "hello" << endl;
    }
    void fB(int x) {
        cout << "good bye" << endl;
    }
    A() {
    }
};

class B {
private:
    void (A:: * f)(int) = NULL;
public:
    B(void (A:: * f)(int)) {
        this->f = f;
    }
    void call() {
        (this->*f)(10); //What's wrong here?
    }
};
A a = A();
B b = B(&(a.fA));
B b2 = B(&(a.fB));

int main(void) {
    b.call();
    b2.call();
}
```

Comment: Normal member functions are static. A pointer to them is not a pointer through the class instance (as with variables). Instead, they are passed a hidden 'this' pointer on class which indicates the instance. Therefore, `&(a.fA)` has no meaning.

Comment: Instead of using function pointers I suggest that you look into `std::funtional`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&(a.fA)` is [not legal C++ syntax](https://godbolt.org/z/Eosfz5nYa). `&A::fA` is. As you can see, there is no object of type A anywhere of this syntax. `&A::fA` is *just* a pointer to a member function, not a pointer-to-member-together-with-an-object combo.

Now in order to call that pointer-to-member, you need an object of class `A`. In class `B`, you don't have any. You need to get one in there somehow, and call the function this way:

```
 (a->*f)(10);
```

where `a` is a pointer to that object of class `A`.